# DataAnnotations vs .Map Functions Database Model Mapping?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping, data-annotations

Which one is better and why?

```
[Table("Bar")]
public class Bar { 
    [Key]
    public Int32 BarId { get; set; }
    public String BarName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class BarMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bar> {
    public BarMap() {
        this.HasMany(t => t.Foos)
            .WithMany(t => t.Bars)
            .Map(m => {
                m.ToTable("FooBarRelationships");
                m.MapLeftKey("TheBarId");
                m.MapRightKey("TheFooId");
            });
    }
}
```

I know the first one is called DataAnnotations but don't know how can we call the second type.

Comment: 2nd type pattern looks like fluent-validation, which is visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second is called *Fluent API (fluent configuration)*.

From my point of view, I would prefer the second option which can separate lots of Attributes out of models. It would make the models cleaner.

Comment: But with the second one i need two class right? A model and a modelmap. Im right? Even having one more class you prefer the secons pattern?

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes: does not matter one or two classes, two classes does not mean you add more complication in your app, it's separation of concern, that's the way to organize and manage the code.